# launching another application from my application in linux

Tags: 20.04

I have a usecase where I want to launch another application from my application, like we have in mobile application where for ex,we get redirected to payment app from our app. How is the same possible in linux, Is there some mechanism for that because I did not find any resources on that?

Comment: You should look into the programming language you use to write your application to find the function/method that can call other system executables/applications and use it to launch and pass arguments to the target application .., Other than that you can rely on the default applications set in the OS to open certain files, but the latter is a rather clumsy way and not recommended.